# Show strongly typed dropdowlist in my ASP.NET-MVC5 razor form

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, forms

I need to show strongly typed dropdowlist in my ASP.NET-MVC5 razor @html.begin form. There are three model class involve within this form. One is course which fill by user and another two school and campus which needs to show in dropdownlist. I have created ViewModel to combine all three and pass along with school and campus list of data in object.

Now I need to show this dropdown in razor form, how I do that???? I need to select ID of school and campus of selected title from dropdown.

### Controller

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateStudentCourse()
    {

        var _studentCourseModel = new StudentCourse_ViewModel
        {
            _schoolList = _studentProfileServices.GetAllSchools(),
            _CampusList = _studentProfileServices.GetAllCampus()
        };

        return PartialView("CreateStudentCourse_Partial", _studentCourseModel);
    }
```

### ViewModel

```
 public class StudentCourse_ViewModel 
{
    public StudentCourse_ViewModel() { }

    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Course ID")]
    public int CourseID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Student ID")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Require Your Student ID")]
    public int StudentID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "School ID")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Require Your School Title")]
    public int SchoolID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Campus ID")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Require Your Campus Title")]
    public int CampusID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Course Title")]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Require Your Course Title")]
    public string CourseTitle { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Mode Of Study")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Require Mode Of Study")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ModeOfStudy { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Study Level")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Require Your Study Level")]
    public string StudyLevel { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Of Course Start")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Require Date of Your Start")]
    public System.DateTime DateOfCourseStart { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Year Of Study")]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Require Your Year Of Study")]
    public string YearOfStudy { get; set; }

    // following are from another class model
    public List<School> _schoolList { get; set; }
    public List<Campus> _CampusList { get; set; }

}
```

### School Model

```
[Table("School")]
public class School
{
    public School() { }

    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "School ID")]
    public int SchoolID { get; set; }


    [MaxLength(150)]
    [Display(Name = "School Title")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Require School Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

   // public Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

### Campus Model

```
    [Table("Campus")]
public class Campus
{
    public Campus() { }

    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Campus ID")]
    public int CampusID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(150)]
    [Display(Name = "Site")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Require Site Title")]
    public string Site { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(150)]
    [Display(Name = "Region")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Require Campus's Region")]
    public string Region { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250)]
    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Require Campus' Address ")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250)]
    [Display(Name = "Town")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Require Campus's Town ")]
    public string Town { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(150)]
    [Display(Name = "PostCode")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Require Campus's PostCode")]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }

    //public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

### Razor Partial View

```
@model App.DAL.Model.StudentCourse_ViewModel


@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateStudentCourse", "StudentProfile", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "CreateStudentCourseForm" }))
 { ............my code here ... 
 I need drop down for _schoolList and _CampusList???????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

School:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SchoolID, new SelectList(_schoolList, "SchoolID ", "Title", Model.SchoolID))
```

Campus:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CampusID, new SelectList(_CampusList, "CampusID ", "Site", Model.CampusID))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found easier solution, send the model of class i.e. in my case course for user to fill it and create viewBag selectList object and use in razor view..

### Controller

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateStudentCourse()
    {

        ViewBag.Schools = new SelectList(_studentProfileServices.GetAllSchools(), "SchoolID", "Title");

        ViewBag.Campus = new SelectList(_studentProfileServices.GetAllCampus(), "CampusID", "Site");

        return PartialView("CreateStudentCourse_Partial");
    }
```

### My View

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Your School", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Schools", null, "Select School", new { id ="schoolList", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
```